# How do I make bullets in a list intersect with bullets from another list, when both lists are not in the same class?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have the initial "Game1" class, with a "Ship" class initiated inside, and within the "Ship" class there's a List, where the "Bullet" class is used.

How can I make a bullet in a list from one of the ship classes intersect with a bullet from the other ship's bullet list?

Do I have to make a list of Rectangles too for their hitboxes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's wise to create an object manager if your game is using collisions.  The object manager will contain a list of all of your game objects, then check collision between all of them in one go, usually with a function that they all derive from a common parent class.  If the objects collide, they then call another function for handling their collision.  You can pass in the object it collided with if it has a specific reaction depending on what it collided with.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how to approach that kind of situation! I'll try to meddle around using that concept.